# Can I pull power from a 20A outlet to rectify faulty #14 three-way switch wiring?

Tags: electrical

I have a 15 amp three way lighting circuit where I ran the 14 gauge two wire cable to the wrong box, the same box that has two wire going to the fixture. There will only be one light on this circuit. Near the other box is a 20 amp outlet that I could acquire power from.

The power going in will be 12 gauge two wire attached to a three way switch and then traveling via 14 gauge 3 wire to the other box, then 14 gauge 2 wire to the fixture.

Is this safe?  Would using 20 amp rated switches make a difference?

Comment: Since there are 3 wires between the two switches, is there some reason why you can't make it work?  You'd have to use the white wire as one of the travelers, so no neutral at the one switch, but I think that's okay as long as it's available at one of the two switches

Comment: @user28910   The OP said he had 14/3 between the 3 way switches, presumably with ground, so electrically it could be made to work.  But putting 14 ga on a 20 amp circuit isn't code legal unless the breaker feeding the circuit is downgraded to 15 amps and the wire in the panel for that circuit has a label indicating there is 14 ga in part of the circuit.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson  No new connections to another 20A branch needed.  Use existing cabling.  I'll throw it out as an answer

Comment: The answer of user28910 is a safe and simple way to deal with this. If the current cable between the two switches is 14/3 + gnd, then you have all the conductors necessary to wire the two 3-way switches even though you have the line cable and the load cable in the same box. Connect the line hot to one of the insulated wires (e.g., the black) and connect this wire to the common of the far switch.  The load hot is connected to the common of the near switch. The other two wires in the /3 cable (red and white) are the travelers. The white neutral of the line cable connects to the load neutral

Comment: How about telling us what is happening on this?

Answer (score 4):

The breaker needs to be sized to protect all the wire in the circuit. The switches need to be sized to safely carry the loads.

- Since 14 AWG wire is only allowed for 15A circuits, a circuit with a mix of 14 AWG and 12 AWG wire must have a 15A breaker.
- Once you have a 15A breaker, the maximum load on the circuit, including any on any switches in the circuit (since the maximum a switch could control is the entire available circuit) is 15A.
- Therefore, only 15A switches are needed here. 20A is OK, just as 12 AWG wire is OK, but everything will still be limited to 15A.

As I understand it (code experts please confirm/deny/correct me) a 20A circuit can have 15A switches if the switches control hardwired lights that are less than 15A (or actually, less than 12A because of continuous use derate) but that if the switches control *receptacles* then the switches must be rated for 20A, even if they are 15A receptacles, because a duplex 15A receptacle on a 20A circuit is allowed and could actually have a 20A load (e.g., 2 x 10A).

If you decide to pull power for a must-be-15A circuit (because of 14 AWG wire) then you not only need to make the obvious replacement of the 20A breaker with a 15A breaker but if you have any actual 20A receptacles - NEMA 6-20R [like this example from Leviton via Amazon](https://amzn.to/3Vz3RF2):

[image: Leviton 6-20R duplex]

then you need to replace them with 15A receptacles. You can have 15A receptacles on a 20A circuit (as long as the circuit serves more than just a single receptacle) but you can't have 20A receptacles on a 15A circuit.

Answer (score 4):

No. You can't put 14ga on a 20 amp circuit.  Breakers are intended to protect installed wiring, not devices.  There's nothing wrong with using a 20 amp switch on a 15 amp circuit.  The only way to salvage this is to swap out the 20 amp breaker with a 15 amp one, label the wire in the panel indicating part of the circuit is 14ga.  Otherwise, you'll need to replace all the 14 ga with 12 ga.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need neutral at both switches, you can make the existing wiring work by using a switch loop.  (I'm aware that neutrals need to be available at switches nowadays, but I recall reading that on a three-way circuit it only needs to be available at one of the switches. Code experts please weigh in)

Also, your switch box (with the three cables) needs to be kinda large, 20 cubic inch min, or 22 if equipped with internal clamps

At the box with the cable coming from the panel, connect the white (neutral) from panel the to the white going to the fixture. Connect the black (hot) from the panel to the common terminal on the switch.

Still at this box, for the 14/3 cable: Take the white wire, mark it with red tape, and connect it to one of the traveler terminals on the switch.  Connect the red to the other traveler terminal.  Connect the black wire to the black going to the fixture.

At the other box: Connect the white (again mark it with red tape) and red wires to the traveler terminals.  Connect the black to the common terminal.

Comment: Great answer.   But we can't forget that the OP is mixing 14 ga and 12 ga on the same circuit and that needs to be identified.

Comment: @George Anderson I think this answer recommends the OP use the existing 15 A circuit wired in #14. There is 14/3 + gnd between the two switches. Two of those would be travelers, but the third could be used to take line hot to the common of the far switch.  This would mean there could not be a neutral in the far switch box, but the circuit would work.